# Como imprimir um número decimal com ponto, não com vírgula?

Tags: java, formatação

Se eu faço:

```
float a=5;
System.out.printf("%d", a);
```

A saída dele será:

> 5,000000

Como faço para imprimir `5.000000`? Ou seja, quero substituir a vírgula por ponto.

Comment: Você quer isso pra aplicação inteira ou somente para este dado? Se quer mudar em geral pra todas as aplicações, é configuração do OS. Se quer mudar na sua aplicação inteira, pode ser o caso de definir o locale. Se quer mudar apenas em alguns casos especificos, e deixar o resto dos números da sua aplicação com vírgula, ja é o caso de trabalhar separadamente nos ítens. Seria legal [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer.

Comment: então o idioma do SO define se vai ser ponto ou vírgula? se eu mandar o .jar pra um pc com SO em inglês ele vai imprimir com ponto? se for o caso, é inevitável?

Comment: tem casos e casos. O melhor amigo pra saber o que acontece no seu caso específico é o teste. Toquei em 3 possibilidades, mas tem mais coisas a se levar em consideração.  Fiz as especulações baseado no que dá pra imaginar pela pergunta, só testando na situação real para aferir melhor.

Comment: acho que é o suficiente pra mim

Answer (score 7):

Talvez isso te ajude:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Teste {
    public static NumberFormat seuFormato() {
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ROOT);
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        return new DecimalFormat("#0.00", symbols);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat formatter = seuFormato();
        float a = 5;
        System.out.println(formatter.format(a));
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no Ideone.](http://ideone.com/Ftl3ZO)

Obtido com base em [um exemplo do site da Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo de forma bem simples você pode usar o `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US)` acima do Scanner.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

O `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US)` vai receber o valor com ponto e imprimir com o ponto.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    double x;
    System.out.println("Digite um valor double: ");
    x = sc.nextDouble();
            
    System.out.printf("O valor de x é: %f", x);
            
    sc.close();
}
// "O valor de x é: 5.000000"
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que usando o replace() , resolve seu problema um exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.replace('o', 'T'));

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.replace('l', 'D'));
   }
```

Resultado:

```
WelcTme tT TutTrialspTint.cTm
WeDcome to TutoriaDspoint.com
```

Comment: Replace **não** é recomendado para converter números, pois a formatação de números depende da localidade em que a JVM está configurada, podendo ora retornar vírgulas ora pontos, além de que números com separadores de milhares como `1.234,45` também vão dar resultados incorretos.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, realmente esqueci dessa possibilidade faz todo sentido :)